# cannot import name 'train_unsupervised' from 'fastText' (unknown location)

Tags: python, machine-learning, fasttext

Currently I am working on stack overflow tag predictor where I am using fasttext.

I install fasttext when I am running the line :

```
import fastText as fasttext

from fastText import train_supervised
```

I get the error

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-176-72aec327c85a> in <module>

----> 1 from fastText import train_supervised

ImportError: cannot import name 'train_supervised' from 'fastText' (unknown location)
```

Can someone help me please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `fastText` should be spelled as `from fasttext import train_supervised`.

This might help -https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/python/doc/examples/train_supervised.py

Comment: @Prashant_Kumar thnx a lot.. This is helpful.